# Is the decrease in wavelength proportional to the reduction in speed?

Tags: speed-of-light, diffraction, home-experiment, wavelength

I conducted a small at home experiment where I compared a red laser’s wavelength through water vs air. I put a diffraction grating in water and then did the same out of water. See photo[image]
It was difficult to measure the wavelengths accurately due to the short travel distance, but it is clear that the under water separation is smaller. I got 507nm for the under water wavelength, but as I mentioned above I question its accuracy. Should the wavelength be 487nm? This with the original frequency would produce a speed of 225,000,000m/s, light’s speed in water.

Comment: Yes. wave speed = wavelength * frequency, i.e., $v = f \lambda$, so $v$ is certainly proportional to $\lambda$.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to point out the fact that the energy of the photon equals
$$E = hf = h \frac{c_{m}}{\lambda_m}$$
where $f$ is the frequency, $h$ the planck constant, $\lambda_m$ the wave length in the medium and $c_{m}$ the speed of light inside the medium the photon travels in

and is conserved in this particular case (the photon only interacts with other charged elementary particles).
 Since $h$ is a constant the frequency $f$ must be conserved, hence the relation $\frac{c_{m}}{\lambda_m}=const$.
You see that as the wave length decreases in a denser medium the speed must decrease too and vice versa.
It holds that $c_m \propto \lambda_m$ with the proportionality-factor $f$.

Comment: But the photon has no charge.

Comment: Who said that the photon is charged?

Comment: How does the photon interact with other charged particles?

Comment: The interaction between photons and electrons is pretty well known, there is for example the so called Compton-effect and the photoelectric-effect (the subject Einstein received his Nobel - price for). There are some more, pretty complex, interactions. But this would definitely be too much for this particular question. The best way to go is that you do some research on the internet and eventually create an extra question here on stacked change (or search trough similar questions)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Definitely do that, quantum mechanics is pretty interesting.