# If the velocity of light is different in different medium is it wavelength changes or frequency changes?

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics, dispersion

We know that the velocity of light is equal to the product of it's wavelength and frequency. And when light goes from vacuum to any other medium it's velocity changes depending the mediums refractive index. 
So does the velocity of light in medium other than vacuum remains the product of wavelength and frequency?
If so does the wavelength changes in different medium? or is it the frequency that changes?
If red light remains red light in different medium then is the color of light attributable to frequency or wavelength?

Comment: Think of light wavefronts passing from one medium to another one without pileup

Comment: All explained here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index

Comment: Check out my question and experiment on this very topic https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365248/129433

Comment: Frequency is controlled by the source, NOT the medium that the light is passing through.